# unzipping all .tgz files in folder to a specific folder

Tags: linux

I am new to linux and I am trying the following:

I have directory data. In this directory there are x files that end with *.tgz. I want to unpack each, and store the output in a new folder. So as an example. I start with:

```
ls data

folder_a.tgz    folder_b.tgz    folder_c.tgz
```

I want want to end up with:

```
ls /data/test/
folder_a    folder_b    folder_c
```

I have tried the following:

```
ls *.tgz | xargs -n1 tar zxvf -C /data/test/
```

Which gives the error:

```
-C cannot open: no such file or directory
```

I do not understand why this does not work, since these both work as expected:

```
tar zxvf folder_a.tgz -C /data/test/
ls *.tgz | xargs -n1 tar zxvf
```

But combining these does not work. Can anyone help me to achieve the goal, and maybe explain why my solution does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that xargs puts the argument at the end, but tar requires the filename after the `f` flag. The following should work:

```
ls *.tgz | xargs -n1 tar zxv -C /data/test/ -f
```

But maybe just using a loop will be the better solution here:

```
for ARCHIVE in *.tgz; do tar xvzf "$ARCHIVE" -C /data/test; done
```

or alternatively:

```
ls *.tgz | while read ARCHIVE; do tar xvzf "$ARCHIVE" -C /data/test; done
```